# How do I open the JIRA comment box externally

Tags: jira

When we want to add a comment to JIRA, we just click on the comment page and the edit box pops up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxc7r.png)

However, I made an external plug-in to open the box and insert content directly through JS, and I found that I could not edit the box through JS.
Although I was able to find the box'S ID through the page, when I tried to retrieve it, the page told me it didn't find the element.
Is there any way to operate this box through JS?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW75V.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5zVI.png)

Comment: You're going to have to post some code and expand on "the page told me it didn't find the element."

Comment: Can you post the JS code and the element you are trying to grab in the question please?